# Variables created outside the Update()

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, move

Let's imagine I have a creature that moves:

```
        bool pathFound = false;
        void Update()
        {
            if(!pathFound)
            {
                //Find a destination point
                pathFound = true;
            }

            //Move creature to point

            if(Creature reached the point)
            {
                pathFound = false;
            }
        }
```

So that the movement depends on the variable created outside the function.
If i want to add exactly the same second creature the code is going to be dublicated:

```
        bool pathFound1 = false;
        bool pathFound2 = false;
        void Update()
        {
            if(!pathFound1)
            {
                //Find a destination point 1
                pathFound1 = true;
            }
            //Move creature 1 to point 1
            if(Creature reached the point 1)
            {
                pathFound1 = false;
            }

            if(!pathFound2)
            {
                //Find a destination point 2
                pathFound2 = true;
            }
            //Move creature 2 to point 2
            if(Creature2 reached the point 2)
            {
                pathFound2 = false;
            }
        }
```

What looks very strange and unefficient to me. And even if I will move all these steps in a function there should be created two almost the same functions with only difference in pathFound1 and pathFound2.
So I wonder how to achive the same result with more qualitative code?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what this class is going to be doing?  Is it suppose to be a manager that moves multiple creatures? AKA Like a single Manager that would move a squad of guys?  Or is this suppose to be like a Koopa, and you have another Koopa that does his own movement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put boolean `pathFound` as `public` member in `Creature`, with default value initialized to `false`.

Then you can have:

```
void Update()
    {
        foreach (Creature creature in yourCreaturesList)
        {
            if (creature.PathFound)
            {
                //Find a destination point for creature
                creature.PathFound = true;
            }

            //Move creature to its target point
            if(creature reached the point)
            {
                creature.PathFound = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

If required, encapsulate other parameters inside the Creature class too.

Comment: I don't have Creature class.I find creatures by FindGameObjectsWithTag. So that the best solution will be to create a class that will hold GameObject Creature and pathFound?

Comment: Yes, you may want to also add target point or another variables that may come.